# Need assistance changing the background color of my tab host

Tags: java, xml, colors, tabs

I have been trying and failing to change the background color of my tabs within a tab host, i am very new to java (well coding in general really) and stumped with this. Any concise help really appreciated.

Activity Code (well some of it)

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
Resources res = getResources();     // Resource object to get Drawables    
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();     // The activity TabHost   
TabHost.TabSpec spec;                   Intent intent;                      

// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)    
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, jobActivity.class);    

// Initialise a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost    
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("job").setIndicator(" Job Details ")                   

        .setContent(intent);    
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

and the associated XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background_color">
<TabHost 
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

    <LinearLayout        
    android:orientation="vertical"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
    android:padding="5dp"
    > 
       <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

     </HorizontalScrollView>
            <FrameLayout            
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"           
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"       
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:padding="5dp"
           >  


         </FrameLayout>
     </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

it should be a nice easy answer for someone; i hope!

Many thanks in advance

************ EDIT - updated but still not working code **************************
Have now got the below working code - but it seems that the method setTabColors doesnt work (not even sure as it gets called as the note for the Log is never seen)

```
 public class EPCTabNotesActivity extends TabActivity{


public static final String LOG_TAG = "dbtest";



 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    


setContentView(R.layout.maintab);    


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
Resources res = getResources();     // Resource object to get Drawables    
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();     // The activity TabHost   

TabHost.TabSpec spec;               
Intent intent;                          



// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)    
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, jobActivity.class);    

// Initialise a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost    
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("job").setIndicator(" Job Details ")                   

        .setContent(intent);  

tabHost.addTab(spec);    

// Do the same for the other tabs    

// ..... More tabs

      setTabColors(tabHost);    // need to call setTabColors AFTER all the tabs are added to     thetab spec, else the For loop fails as its empty (therefore = 0)
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);



}

private void setTabColors(TabHost tabHost) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
{   
      tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); //unselected tab

      Log.v(LOG_TAG,    "tab color " );
}
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

i : Refers to the tab whose color is to be set. For example : Snippet below will change color of first tab.

```
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Place this code in activity file.

Comment: Write this code in your activity file and 'i' refers to the tab whose color you want to change. So if there are 3 tabs and you want to change color of first, you can replace i with 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer about the i - makes sense. However, i seem to be having an issue with regards to its static (or non static) nature - will not complie and the eclipse notes states "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getTabWidget() from the type TabHost" - any ideas?

Comment: Are you using it in a class that is static? A class that is static cannot call a non static method. A snippet of your code would have helped. You may refer [link](http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-to-fix-cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method) for more informatiom

Comment: OP updated with my progress - the problem i had above about static and non static was solved (I cant type properly :) )

Comment: Needed to put my method call in a different place 0 then worked - above code editted